# Polar equation of perimeter of half ellipse (concave mirror shape)

Tags: javascript, curve, polar-coordinates

`var x = Cx + a * Math.cos(ang);`

`var y = Cy + b * Math.sin(ang);`

`Cx, Cy` are cords of center. `ang` is angle in `radians`. `a` is half of width, `b` is half of height.

If I change values of `ang`, I get different points on circumference of ellipse. Below is the path, which I get with above equation.

[image: Ellipse]

But instead of this elliptical shape, I want something like half ellipse, something like concave mirror. Even if we stretch both of its end to infinity, they should not form elliptical shape.

[image: Concave]

Can somebody provide me polar equations for second curve. I am very bad at digital drawing, but you can imagine that as concave mirror.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a parabolic, hyperbolic, or catenary shape? A concave reflecting lens is parabolic. Note this question probably might belong the math.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: Yes, I thought that it may be a parabola, but equations of parabola looked very hard to me.

Comment: Are you restricted to using parametric equations in terms of angle?

Comment: No, but , I need to find co-ordinates based on angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametric equations for a parabola with focus at `(Fx, Fy)` and focal parameter `2a`, in terms of angle, would be:

```
x = Fx + (2*a*cos(ang))/(1 + cos(ang))
y = Fy + (2*a*sin(ang))/(1 + cos(ang))
```

Not too bad. :) You can adjust `a` as needed. You can actually modify it a bit by adjusting the ratio of the distances from the focus to the plot, versus the plot to the directrix:

```
x = Fx + (2*a*cos(ang))/(1 + cos(ang))
y = Fy + (2*b*sin(ang))/(1 + cos(ang))
```

Here the ratio will be `b/a`. So you can have the same distance from the origin to the vertex (2a) and make `b` larger to "flatten" the parabola.